# Ratios between Factorial numbers and the sum of their factors

Tags: factoring, factorial

Let a factorial number be called $f!$.  Let the sum of its factors be called $S(f!)$.  Let the ratio between the two be “r”, such that $r=\frac{S}{f!}$.

It is conjectured that: $\frac{S(f+1)!}{(f+1)!} = r+0.5$

In other words; going from one factorial to the next increases the ratio between the sum of the factorial's factors and the factorial by $\frac{1}{2}$.  I have not yet proven this, and have checked it only until to $f!=120$.

For the purposes of this question the sum will not include the factorial itself but it will include 1. The numbers tested so far are:

$0=\frac{0}{1}$

$.5=\frac{1}{2}$

$1=\frac{1+2+3}{6}$

$1.5=\frac{1+2+3+4+6+8+12}{24}$

$2=\frac{1+2+3+4+5+6+8+10+12+15+20+24+30+40+60}{120}$

Comment: I do not understand $1+2+3+4+6+8+12$. Could you clarify for me, please ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici It's the sum of the proper factors of $4!$.

Comment: @ThomasDelaney are you testing manually? I would suggest you to make a small Python (or other programming language) program, there are very quick libraries to make factorials and obtain the factors of a number.

Comment: @user26486. Thanks for clarifying for the old man !

Answer (score 0):

You have
$$\frac{S(7!)}{7!}=\frac{14304}{5040} = \frac{298}{105}$$
so your conjecture fails.